# Using a dynamic values in as array using php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to use some numbers stored in php session inside the array and displaying them in foreach. For example:

```
$stored_values = '123,456,789';
```

Using these values inside array like this:

```
$array = array($stored_values);
```

and then trying foreach like:

```
foreach($array AS $values){
echo $values;
}
```

But the output is coming as one value for example:

```
OUTPUT: 123,456,789
```

Instead of each value separately.

Comment: Simply initializing an array with a single comma separated string does not automatically create multiple entries.Try `$array = explode(',', $stored_values);`. Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/function.explode.php

Comment: yes I already tried like this and its working, Thank you :)